# react-native expo in circleci fails to login: This command requires Expo CLI

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, expo, circleci

I'm setting up a ci/cd pipeline for my expo react-native application using circleci.
I have followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/vermonster/https-medium-com-vermonster-optimize-expo-publish-process-with-circleci-81b9c3e2b942). And this is my `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
publish: &publish
  working_directory: ~/loplop-native
  docker:
    - image: circleci/node:12.14.0
  steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
        name: Restore yarn package cache
        key: v1-cache-dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}
    - run:
        name: Install dependencies
        command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    - save_cache:
        name: Save yarn package cache
        paths:
          - ~/.cache/yarn
        key: v1-cache-dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}
    - run:
        name: Login into Expo
        command: npx expo login -u $EXPO_USERNAME -p $EXPO_PASSWORD
        # command: npx expo login --non-interactive -u $EXPO_USERNAME
    - run:
        name: Save current branch name to an env variable
        command: |
          if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then
            echo 'export EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL="default"' >> $BASH_ENV
          else
            echo 'export EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL=$CIRCLE_BRANCH' >> $BASH_ENV
          fi
    - run:
        name: Publish to Expo
        command: npx expo publish --non-interactive --max-workers 1 --release-channel $EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.14.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restore yarn package cache
          key: v1-cache-dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}
      - run:
          name: Install Expo-cli
          command: yarn global add expo-cli
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - save_cache:
          name: Save yarn package cache
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn
          key: v1-cache-dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}-{{ arch }}

      - run:
          name: Run linting
          command: yarn lint

  publish_to_expo:
    <<: *publish

workflows:
  version: 2
  workflow:
      jobs:
        - build_and_test
        - publish_to_expo:
            filters:
              branches:
                ignore: gh-pages
```

The script is failing on the login step with this error:

[image]

I have also tried with the `--no-interactive` flag but I'm still getting the same error.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Expo CLI first. Run `yarn global add expo-cli` or `npm install -g expo-cli`, then run the Expo commands directly, without `npx` (e.g. `expo login ...`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it also but it does not work. Plus expo commands are executed with 'npx'

Comment: But I saw a similar issue (https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1224#issuecomment-559818811) where the suggestion is to add a "yes" flag for the interactive mode. I applied the suggestion. Now the login error is gone and circleci attemps to install expo-cli globally. 
But I'm getting now a "permission denied" error...

Comment: Where did you see that expo commands are executed with npx? Their docs state clearly that the CLI should be installed globally

Comment: check the expo documentation (the circleci section, especially the authentication step):
https://docs.expo.io/guides/setting-up-continuous-integration/
They clearly use "npx"

Answer (score 0):

It is due to you don't have the dependencies of expo-cli in package.json. You need to add "expo-cli": "1.1.0-beta.4" in package.json under devdependencies.

Reference : https://bitbucket.org/byCedric/expo-guide-ci/src/master/package.json